# Principal component analysis and correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, pca

Hello everyone and good day to you,

Could you please explain how to use principal components in principal component analysis in a correlation analysis? I performed a PCA on my dataset and extracted 2 components form 8 variables; Now I'm wondering how to use pearson or spearman correlation analysis to find out the correlation between PC1(or PC2) and, let's say, another variable.

I mean, I want to do a regression analysis in which my two extracted components are independent variables and each participant's age (for example) is the dependent variable.

How should I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, I think you would just perform correlation or regression analysis as you would with any other set of variables, only now you use the principal components (the data projected onto the 2 selected principal component directions) as your variables.

Here is a good, short article that describes performing regression with principal components:

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat508/lesson/7/7.1

Hope that helps!